# Client certificate: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority (Again!)

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl, soap, tls1.2

Sorry for asking this question, but I couldn't find any answer for my case on Stack.

I developed a client application that talks to an external SOAP api using WCF. To authenticate, the application uses a client certificate. (The client certificate as been installed on the server). When I test on my local machine everything works fine.

The problems occurs when I deploy the application on IIS (on a EC2). The apps cannot communicate with the SOAP api anymore. This is the error:

```
"Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority".
```

I installed the certificate in Personnal store of both Current User and Local Computer location. When I try to hit the SOAP api with the browser it works (get on wsdl file which also need the client certificate).

Note: the certificate is not self signed. It was created by an authorized CA.

Thanks for the help

Comment: So as per my understanding your client app is web app that fetch the certificate from local machine and attach it to the request made to SOAP service. is it?

Comment: Hi Rashmin, yes this is it. Do you have any clue of what can be the problem?

Comment: I changed the Identity of the application pool of IIS to LocalSystem and restarted the app. I think it was a permission problem

Comment: So it is working now?

Comment: yes!! Thanks for looking at my problem Rashmin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certificate Store can only be accessible to Administrators. local iis user that is `IUSER` does not have administrator rights and so u were getting that certificate error. Changing application pool identity to LocalSystem solved your problem because LocalSystem can access to Certificate STore.

Another optimum solution to this is to only allow the access of certificate to IUSER. (by doing this you have given a specific access unlike the full administrator access to app pool).

To do that go to the 
Certificate console -> Right click on Certificate -> All Tasks -> Manage Private Key -> Add `IUSER` and click Ok.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I changed the Identity of the application pool of IIS to LocalSystem and restarted the app. I think it was a permission problem. If someone can explain me why it fixed the problem I would accept her/his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```